# Connect to SQL Azure from Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to an Azure SQL database by creating a new Data Connection from within Visual Studio 2013, latest release for VS and Azure. The database has been created, has tables etc., but I continue to receive the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

- I have ensured that TCP is allowed and above Named Pipes in the Configuration Manager.
- The associated IP address is allowed on Azure Firewall.
- Certificate has been added to VS etc.

Still no connection. I can see the database in the Azure section in Server Explorer, but cannot add a Data Connection.

I have a MacBook Pro running Win 7 sitting right next to my office computer and it can access Azure all right.

Comment: Are you sure that it's enabled your IP Address to connect to it?

Comment: Thiago, Yes. I just checked the IP in Azure. The exact IP was listed. But I went ahead and added another rule to encompass XX.00.00.00 through XX.99.99.99. Still no connection.

Comment: In this case, you'd better create a ticket on Azure Support.

Comment: Just another info: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started/

Comment: Thanks, Tiago. Went to Azure Support and it says my subscription level does not include Technical Support - I'm on the BizSpark program.

Comment: In this case, review the article I've posted above and check if you didn't miss any step.

Comment: I eventually followed a link to Technical Difficulties and found a process to testing using tracert. Looks like the trace didn't even make it out of the switch/router.

Answer (score 3):

The OP gave answer in the comments:

> I eventually followed a link to Technical Difficulties and found a process to testing using tracert. Looks like the trace didn’t even make it out of the switch/router.